# Why we use tf.Variable in tensorflow if we can directly use a variable without initialisation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

In tensorflow we used variables in two ways:

```
a = tf.constant(12)

b = tf.constant(10)

#NOW SAY I WANT TO ADD THESE TWO

#1st method

ans = tf.Variable(tf.add(a, b))

# Initialize the variable
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
print(sess.run(ans))

#2nd method

ans1 = tf.add(a, b)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(ans1)
```

So as we all know that for using 1st method we have to initialize the variable or it will throw an error of "uninitialised variable". But their is no need to do initialization for 2nd method.
So my question is why are we using 1st method or tf.Variable in tensorflow? Is their any specific use of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think of 4 types of tensors in tensorflow:

- Placeholders - these are tensors that expect to find a value passed in via `feed_dict` as part of your `sess.run` call.
- Variables - these are mutable tensors that keep their values from one execution of `sess.run` to the next. Thes are the only types of tensor that maintain their state throughout the life of the session.
- Computed tensors (OPs/operations) - these are computed values such as `tf.add(a,b)`, the value is discarded (or returned) at the end of a call to `sess.run`. They are computed only.
- Constants - e.g. `tf.constant(12)`

Variables need to be initialized precisely because they maintain state, so they need an initial state. This is why you had to run the initializer in method #1.

An OP on the other hand is computed and discarded on every call to `sess.run`. This is what you did in method #2. You performed a computation, and provided everything that was necessary to perform that computation (the two constants). And hence tensorflow performed the requested computation, returned the results to you, then discarded the results.

Notice a unique difference in method #1. If you were to request the value of `ans` at some point in the future with `sess.run(ans)`, it would simply retrieve the value of the variable and return it (no computation performed). In method #2, if you request the value of `ans1` in the future with `sess.run(ans1)` it would have to perform the computations again for you.

Answer (score 1):

`TensorFlow.add` returns a `TensorFlow.Tensor` type. If you cast it to a `TensorFlow.Variable` as in your first method, you have to initialize it but you gain several capabilities, since a `Variable` is a `Tensor` wrapper with advanced functionalities.

For instance, a `Variable` can exist outside the context of a single session.run call, unlike a `Tensor` ([see the doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables)).

So it fully depends on your needs in your situation.